# WCF. Notify one part about death of another

Tags: wcf

I have the following scenario.

My server have event. Client subscribes to this event and then wait till this event will happen.

If client dies, server will know it becouse of exception it will get on firering event.

If server dies - client never knows about it an continue wait. But when server up again he will not know about client, so client will wait forever without result.

My client should be notified about server death, but I can't find an easy way to do it.

I'm using named pipes duplex communication.

It's logically to propose, that if I can't find this functionality in WCF, this means that I just don't need it, and there is another way to realise this scenario. So please can anyone tell me how to do what I whant, or show me the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your service is dead, it can't really notify the clients of its demise :-( So I guess the only option would be for your clients to periodically poll (e.g. every 5 minutes or so), and if they can't get through anymore, assume the server is dead and give up on that connection.

Marc

Comment: I've hoped there is another way.